# Как быть, если вносил правки в тему WordPress, но не знал что нужно создать дочернюю?

Tags: wordpress

Переделывать все заново уже не хочется. Как я понял, я могу просто скопировать папку с темой, закинуть ее в папку "**wp-themes**", и добавить строку "**template**" в файл CSS. Это сработает? После обновления темы изменения не слетят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не сработает. Сайт упадёт с ошибкой 500, потому что в вашей "дочерней" теме будут объявлены те же функции, что и в основной.

Вы можете создать папку в wp-themes с другим именем, записать туда вашу тему и переименовать её в style.css, в поле `Theme name:`

Comment: Еще один вопрос, с плагином woocommerce аналогично?

Comment: Там ещё хуже. Думаю, вы не можете его даже переименовать и закинуть в папку с другим именем. Всё сломается. Вариант один - отключить обновления, указав безумный номер версии в файле woocommerce.php, в поле `Version:`

Comment: Ну а вообще-то нельзя так делать, ведь везде же есть возможности писать обновляемый код. В темах - дочерняя тема, в woocommerce - папка templates, откуда можно копировать шаблоны в свою дочернюю тему. Плюс хуки.

Comment: Спасибо! Это мой первый опыт создания сайта на wordpress, поэтому такие "косяки") Тяжело в учении, легко в бою)

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо! Не занал)